# searching in a specific attribute (column) with Algolia

Tags: php, algolia

I am trying to utilise Algolia's Natural Language search to search amongst my already populated indices, but I only need to search in the "name" column.

I am having a difficult time figuring how to do it. I am using the PHP SDK, and I've managed to facet it, but that only returns `facetHits`, with the value of the hit, but I still need the data from the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `searchableAttributes`.

```
$index->setSettings([
  'searchableAttributes' => [
    'name',
  ]
]);
```

see also [the api reference](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/searchableAttributes/) and [the guide for searchable attributes](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/ranking/searchable-attributes/#searchable-attributes-overview)

Comment: I need the other attributes for another search-field on the site.

Comment: @JapSeyz you can create a replica and have one with all searchable attributes, and another with just name

Comment: Oh, that's smart. Completely missed that feature. Thanks a ton!